# OpenGL version changes when ContextAttribs() value is changed

Tags: java, c++, macos, opengl

I want to change the version of OpenGL that I am using from 3.2 to 3.3 so I can implement instanced rendering.  Currently my OpenGL initialization code looks like this.

```
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
```

So I changed it to...

```
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 3).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
```

The only difference is the version of OpenGL which I put in ContextAttribs().

I am running this aplication on a 2013 MacBook Air that has OpenGL capabilities of up to 4.1 according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823

After creating the display I have placed the following code

```
System.out.println("OpenGL version " + GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));
```

This allows me to check which version of OpenGL I am using.  HERE is the tricky part.  When I put ContextAttribs(3, 2) it prints out

> OpenGL version 4.1 INTEL-10.12.13

However, if I change it to ContextAttribs(3, 3) my application crashes and prints out

> OpenGL version 2.1 INTEL-10.12.13

I have no idea how to fix this and if anyone can it would be MUCH appreciated.  Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [doc](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs.html) for the LWJGL ContextAttribs class. It states:

> However, in order to enable the GL 3.2 context on MacOS X 10.7 or newer, an instance of this class must be passed to LWJGL. The only valid configuration is ContextAttribs(3, 2, CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB), anything else will be ignored.

Comment: If I change it to that will I be able to use OpenGL 3.3, even though it is set to 3.2? Thanks for responding!@nasser